# Why doesn't this code work? Javascript if statement, else if statement

Tags: javascript

This is a javascript code, and I wanted to make it like:
if the person answered yes, reply with "that's cool", if the person answered no, reply with "I'll make you happy", if the person answered a question that CONTAINS "yes" or "no", say "Type only yes or no, without any extra texts." Also, if the person doesn't reply that doesn't CONTAIN "yes" or "no", answer with "you didn't even answer the question."
But, this code is somehow weird. If I type something random like "hi", it says "Type only yes or no, without any extra texts.", not "you didn't even answer the question."
help!

```
var id;
id = prompt("Are you happy?");
if(id == "yes"){
alert("That's cool.");
}else if(id == "no"){
alert("I'll make you happy.");
}else if(id || "yes" || "no"){
alert("Type only yes or no, without any extra texts.");
}else{
alert("you didn't even answer the question.");
}
```

Comment: The expression `id || "yes" || "no"` is always true.

Comment: Use `.contains("yes")` for checking entry text contain yes or not

Comment: That doesn't work. I want to make it as if the answer includes "yes" or "no", make it output "Type only yes or no, without any extra texts." and make "you didn't even answer the question" as a default answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is in line

```
if(id || "yes" || "no")
```

You check whteher the id variable exist or string "yes" exist or string "no" exist. So it is allways true.

If you want to check if string contains some value you can do it either by regular expression ([more](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)) or simply by indexOf eg:

```js
var id;

id = prompt("Are you happy?");

if (id == "yes") {

  alert("That's cool.");
  
} else if(id == "no") {

  alert("I'll make you happy.");
  
} else if(id.indexOf('yes') >= 0 || id.indexOf('no') >= 0) {

  alert("Type only yes or no, without any extra texts.");
  
} else {

  alert("you didn't even answer the question.");
  
}
```

Regards, KJ

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
else if(id || "yes" || "no")
```

doesn't test whether `id` has the values `"yes"` or `"no"` in it. It tests if `id` is truthy*, or `"yes"` is truthy (it is), or `"no"` is truthy (it is). So the overall condition will always be true, regardless of the value of `id`.

Since you're using `else if`, you don't need to check for `"yes"` or `"no"` at all at that point — if you got there, you know `id` doesn't have either of them in it. So just

```
else if (id)
```

...will tell you that `id` has something in it, but it wasn't `"yes"` or `"no"` (because you already handled them).

---

* "truthy" - Coerces to or is treated as `true` when coerced to boolean or used in a logical operation. It's the other side of "falsy," which coerces to or is treated as `false` in the same situations. The falsy values in JavaScript are `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`. All other values are truthy (including `" "`, FWIW).

Comment: then, how am I supposed to fix this? Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @Ardent: As I said above, replace the `else if(id || "yes" || "no")` with `else if (id)`.

Comment: That doesn't work. I want to make it as if the answer includes "yes" or "no", make it output "Type only yes or no, without any extra texts." and make "you didn't even answer the question" as a default answer.

Comment: @Ardent: I still didn't get what you wanted until I saw [Krzysztof's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47636228/157247). I thought by "other texts" you mean "bzzzt" or similar, and that you only wanted the final `else` to apply when they didn't type anything *at all*.